# What is this test case doing?

Tags: python-3.x, function

This is my function:

```
def ecu_data(a_id, data):
    """ Returns a list of the timestamp and data of an ID. """
    result = []
    arb_index = data[0].index("ID")
    for row in data[1:]:
        if row[arb_index] == a_id:
            result.append(row)
    return result
```

and one of the test cases is:

```
data = get_data("file.csv")
edata = ecu_data('153', data)
print(edata[22])
```

It appears to give the right answer, but I'm not exactly sure what the test case is doing. Originally I assumed it was checking in the 22nd line but the answer actually points to the 532nd line in the file. What does the [22] mean when the code is being executed?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! The test case `print(edata[22])` is printing the 23rd element (index 22) in the list `edata` that is returned from the function `ecu_data`. The list `edata` contains all rows in data where the value in the column "ID" is equal to `153`

Comment: @Ake Hi thank you! This helped a ton. Just another question: I ran my code to only print out the data that corresponds with the ID `153` and counted to triple check what you said (which makes complete sense) but the 23rd element was not printed as index 22, the 24th element was. It is the same for other indexes as well. Any ideas why?

Comment: It's possible that the reason you're seeing this discrepancy is because your function only returns rows that match the specified ID, which means that the index of the row in the original data list might not be the same as the index of the row in the returned result list. Another possibility is that there are missing rows in the original data list that are not returned by your function.  Keep in mind that the index of a row in a list can change depending on how the list is filtered or manipulated.

Answer (score -1):

It presumably returns the 23rd (since Python is zero-indexed but English is one-indexed) row that has an ID of 153.